# MySQL query for alphabetical search

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

How to retrieve the records those character star starting with `A` OR `B` OR `C` ,

I just tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE Left(cus_name, 1) = 'a'

 ---> display all customer name starting with character a
```

AND I added one more condition, That is

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE Left(cus_name, 1) = 'a' or Left(cus_name, 1) = 'b'

 --->It  displayed all customer name starting with character a and in some records middle i saw some name starting with b also,
```

What i want is , i want pull out records , which names are starting with `A` or `B` or `C` ,

And also it should order by alphabetical order,

Also i tried this below query.

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE Left(cus_name, 1) REGEXP '^[^a-z]+$';
```

The rendered records for that above is , just two records started with `A`,

This above question for doing the alphabetical pagination ,

Thanks

Comment: i thing , this will fix my problem REGEXP '^(A|D|F)' order by cus_name asc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE cus_name REGEXP '^[abc]';
```

It will list all rows where `cus_name` starts with either `a`, `b` or `c`.

The regex used is `^[abc]`:

- `^`  : Is the start anchor
- [..] : Is the character class. So `[abc]` matches either an `a` or a `b` or a `c`. It is equivalent to `(a|b|c)`

The regex you were using : `^[^a-z]+$`

- The first `^` is the start anchor.
- [..] is character class.
- The `^` inside the character class
  negates it. So `[^abc]` is any
  character other than the three
  listed.
- `+` is the quantifier for one or
  more.
- `$` is the end anchor.

So effectively you are saying: give me all the rows where `cus_name` contains one or more letters which cannot be any of the lowercase letters.

Comment: REGEXP '^(A|D|F)' order by cus_name asc , this one ok Sir

Comment: It'll list all the rows where `cus_name` starts with either `A` or `D` or `F` and will sort the rows in ascending order of `cus_name`.

Comment: Remember, anything REGEXPed requires full table scan. And probably, ignores indexes.

Answer (score 3):

try like instead

```
SELECT * FROM `test_tbl` WHERE cus_name like 'a%'
```